# Bulk Upload of Enrollments in D2L Valence

Tags: integration, desire2learn, valence

It appears to be that D2L / Brightspace Valence only allows enrollment creation one at a time.

Enrollment.CreateEnrollmentData
http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/enroll.html

We receive enrollment data from our campus student information system in CSV files - am I correct in understanding we would need to spin through these files and post each enrollment one by one?

It seems like this would be a pretty common scenario....I'm surprised there isn't a bulk enrollment API?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The Brightspace API only allows creation and enrollment one user at a time. The API currently has endpoints for bulk course creation. So it would be worth asking for bulk student enrollment feature on D2Ls product forums.

The only other alternative is D2Ls " [Integration Pack for Student Information Systems (IPSIS)](https://documentation.brightspace.com/EN/integrations/ipsis/admin/using_ipsis_handlers.htm) "
Which can serve bulk enrollments